# How to enter SysPrep in Windows 7 AFTER I exited it?

Tags: windows-7

I installed win7 and entered sysprep (ctrl shift f3), installed some apps and I forgot to uninstall one that was needed while in sysprep, bow I can't start windows because it crashes, and the app I forgot to uninstall does that...

any way I can enter sysprep again to uninstall this app? I already generalized with oobe etc...

or I need to reinstall everything again? :(

thanks!

Comment: Do you mean that your trying to get into audit mode?

Answer (score 1):

If you've left OOBE enabled in your sysprep config, when the machine comes up and prompts you for machine name, license key, etc, press Shift+Ctrl+F3 again.  This drops you into Audit mode, where you can configure the machine.  Once you've finished repairing the install, run sysprep again using the same options you did the first time.

If the machine is crashing before it gets to that point, then reinstalling may be your best option.  Alternatively, if the problematic program causes a crash when it loads, you could boot into a WinPE environment and edit the registry to prevent it from starting on boot.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the good old safe mode?

Boot the machine and press F8

Select Safe Mode

This will boot the machine with bare minimum of drivers ect loaded